# How to configure u -turn nat in palo Alto firewalls

Tags: palo-alto

My requirements is users wants to access public hosted web -sites of same organization from intranet we are having palo alto firewall deployed as perimeter firewalls

Comment: You're better off using a split-brain name server that resolves names to internal addresses for internal users.

Comment: Fix your DNS to return internal addresses for internal users. Do not waste your firewall and router resources and bandwidth for internal network traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially all you need to do is set the source zone to your internal zone, the destination zone to your external facing zone, the destination interface to be "any", the source address to be your inside subnet/host, the destination address to be your webserver's PUBLIC IP address, the translated source to be your firewalls INSIDE interface address, and the translated destination to be your webserver's PRIVATE IP address.

You can see a better explanation of what's needed [here](https://knowledgebase.paloaltonetworks.com/KCSArticleDetail?id=kA10g000000ClEiCAK)